# How to Display results in the other form for Java NetBeans?

Tags: java, forms, swing, netbeans

I want the button "Submit" to open the form with the value set to the textfields, checked item, selected radio button to be in the jLabels and the jLabel in the desktoppane for the image in the second form

[image: (Click this link to see the screenshot of the forms)]

> /*  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project
> Properties.  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
>
> - and open the template in the editor.  */ package employeeapplication; import java.io.File; import
>   javax.swing.ImageIcon; import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
>
> /**  *  * @author irecu  */ public class Empmenu extends
> javax.swing.JFrame {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Creates new form Empmenu
>  */
> public Empmenu() {
>     initComponents();
>     
> }
>
> Submitted submit = new Submitted();
>
> public class Empmennu extends Submitted{
>     
> }
>
> /**
>  * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
>  * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
>  * regenerated by the Form Editor.
>  */
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
> // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
> private void initComponents() {
>
>     jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
>     jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jDesktopPane1 = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
>     jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
>     jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
>     jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
>     jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
>     jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
>     jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
>     jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
>     jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
>     jRadioButton4 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
>     jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
>     jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
>     jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
>     jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
>     jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
>
>     setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
>     setAutoRequestFocus(false);
>     setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 600));
>     setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
>     setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 600));
>     setResizable(false);
>     setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 800));
>     setType(java.awt.Window.Type.POPUP);
>
>     jButton1.setText("Upload");
>     jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>
>     jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
>     jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
>     jLabel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
>     jLabel1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.LEFT);
>
>     jDesktopPane1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
>     jDesktopPane1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(280, 280));
>
>     jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
>     jLabel2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(280, 280));
>     jLabel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(280, 280));
>
>     jDesktopPane1.setLayer(jLabel2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
>
>     javax.swing.GroupLayout jDesktopPane1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDesktopPane1);
>     jDesktopPane1.setLayout(jDesktopPane1Layout);
>     jDesktopPane1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
>         jDesktopPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
>         .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 224,
> ```
>
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> );
> jDesktopPane1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
> jDesktopPane1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 207,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> );
>
> ```
>     jLabel3.setText("Name");
>
>     jLabel4.setText("Occupation");
>
>     jLabel5.setText("Age Category:");
>
>     jLabel6.setText("Employment:");
>
>     jLabel7.setText("Filipino?:");
>
>     jLabel8.setText("TIN:");
>
>     jLabel9.setText("Gender:");
>
>     jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Employed", "Self-Employed", "Un-Employed" }));
>
>     jScrollPane2.setName(""); // NOI18N
>
>     jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
>         String[] strings = { "Minor: Under 18", "Adult: 18 to 59", "Senior: 60 Above" };
>         public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
>         public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
>     });
>     jList1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
>     jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList1);
>
>     jCheckBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>
>     jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>     jTextField3.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
>         public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
>             jTextField3KeyTyped(evt);
>         }
>     });
>
>     jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>
>     jRadioButton3.setText("Male");
>
>     jRadioButton4.setText("Female");
>     jRadioButton4.setToolTipText("");
>
>     jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
>     jTextArea2.setRows(5);
>     jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextArea2);
>
>     jButton3.setText("Submit");
>     jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>
>     jButton4.setText("Preview Details");
>     jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>
>     jButton2.setText("Clear");
>     jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>
>     javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
>     getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
>     layout.setHorizontalGroup(
>         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
>         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
>             .addContainerGap()
>             .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
>                 .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
> ```
>
> false)
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addComponent(jLabel4)
> .addGap(18, 18, 18)
> .addComponent(jTextField2))
> .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
> layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addComponent(jLabel6)
> .addComponent(jLabel8)
> .addComponent(jLabel7)
> .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
> .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
> false)
> .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
> .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 162, Short.MAX_VALUE)
> .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> .addComponent(jTextField1)
> .addComponent(jTextField3)))
> .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
> layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addGap(75, 75, 75)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
> .addComponent(jRadioButton4))))
> .addComponent(jLabel3)
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addGap(28, 28, 28)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
> false)
> .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 162, Short.MAX_VALUE)
> .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
> .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
> .addGap(65, 65, 65)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addComponent(jButton1)
> .addGap(18, 18, 18)
> .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
> .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 359,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
> .addGap(30, 30, 30))
> );
> layout.setVerticalGroup(
> layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addGap(45, 45, 45)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
> .addComponent(jLabel8)
> .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
> .addComponent(jLabel3)
> .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
> .addGap(21, 21, 21)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
> .addComponent(jLabel4)
> .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
> .addGap(18, 18, 18)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
> layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addComponent(jLabel5)
> .addGap(31, 31, 31)))
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
> .addComponent(jLabel6)
> .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
> .addGap(18, 18, 18)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,
> false)
> .addComponent(jCheckBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
> .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
> .addComponent(jDesktopPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
> .addGap(24, 24, 24)))
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addGap(30, 30, 30)
> .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addGap(19, 19, 19)
> .addComponent(jLabel9))
> .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
> .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
> .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
> .addComponent(jRadioButton4)))
> .addGap(18, 18, 18)
> .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> .addGap(16, 16, 16)
> .addComponent(jButton2)
> .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
> .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35,
> javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
> .addGap(0, 5, Short.MAX_VALUE))
> .addComponent(jScrollPane3))
> .addGap(22, 22, 22))
> );
>
> ```
>     pack();
> }// </editor-fold>                        
>
> private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>     JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
>     chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
>     File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
>     jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(f.toString()));
>     filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
>     jLabel1.setText(filename);
>     
>     
> }                                        
>
> private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>     if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
>         jTextField3.setEnabled(true);
>     }
>     else{
>         jTextField3.setEnabled(false);
>     }
> }                                          
>
> private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
> }                                           
>
> private void jTextField3KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>     char character = evt.getKeyChar();
>     if (((character < '0') || (character > '9'))
>         && (character != '\b')) {
>         evt.consume();
>
>     }
>
> }                                    
>
> private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
> }                                           
>
> private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>     jTextArea2.append("Name: " + jTextField1.getText()+"\n" );
>     jTextArea2.append("Occupation: " + jTextField2.getText()+"\n");
>     if(jList1.isSelectionEmpty()){
>         jTextArea2.append("Age Category: null \n");
>     }
>     else{
>         jTextArea2.append("Age Category: " + jList1.getSelectedValuesList().toString()+"\n");
>     }
>     jTextArea2.append("Employment: " + jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n");
>     if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
>         jTextArea2.append("Filipino: Yes"+ "\n");
>         jTextArea2.append("TIN: "+ jTextField3.getText() + "\n");
>     }
>     else{
>         jTextArea2.append("Filipino: No" + "\n");
>     }
>
>     if(jRadioButton3.isSelected()){
>         jTextArea2.append("Gender: " + jRadioButton3.getText() + "\n" + "\n");
>     }
>     else{
>         jTextArea2.append("Gender: " + jRadioButton4.getText() + "\n" +"\n");
>     }
>     jTextArea2.append("\n");
> }                                        
>
> private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
>     jTextArea2.setText("");
> }                                        
>
> private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
>     
>         
>     submit.setVisible(true);
>
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
> }                                        
>
> /**
>  * @param args the command line arguments
>  */
> public static void main(String args[]) {
>     /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
>     //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
>     /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
>      * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
>
>      */
>     try {
>         for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
>             if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
>                 javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>     } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
>         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empmenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
> ```
>
> null, ex);
> } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
> java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empmenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
> null, ex);
> } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
> java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empmenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
> null, ex);
> } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
> java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Empmenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
> null, ex);
> }
> //
>
> ```
>     /* Create and display the form */
>     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
>         public void run() {
>             new Empmenu().setVisible(true);
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
> private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
> private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
> private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
> private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
> private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
> private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
> private javax.swing.JDesktopPane jDesktopPane1;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
> private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
> private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
> private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
> private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton4;
> private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
> private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
> private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
> private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
> private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
> private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
> // End of variables declaration
> ```
>
> byte[] photo=null; String filename=null; }

Comment: *"Click this link to the Project"* ... no. Some people cannot click external links (company policy etc. Most won't. The vast majority of those worth listening to, won't. Code should be include as text in the question itself. And what I mean by 'code' is a [mre].

Comment: A few points: 1) There is a preview below the code posting / editing form. Carefully examine it before posting, to check it formats as you expect. 2) (Related to that) Please use code formatting (**not** 'quoted material') for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 3) That code dump is not short enough to be called a [mre]. Please take more effort in future, to reduce the problem to the simplest form that actually demonstrates the problem. ..

Comment: .. In this case, the problem needs 2 frames, two text fields (one for input, the other for output) and an action listener added to the input field. Maybe one button to pop the second frame up. ***All*** the other components are unnecessary to display the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this sort of thing. Off hand, a simple way would be to create another class which extends JFrame named **SubmissionForm** then Create a constructor for this new class that will accept all the required information to display, for example (non-runnable):

```
// Your first form's class (just an example)
public class DataEntryForm extends JFrame {
 
    public DataEntryForm() {
        initializeForm();
    }

    // ... all your other class code ...

    private void initializeForm() {
        // Create an ActionListener
        submitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                submitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
     
        // ... all the other code required to create your form ...
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DataEntryForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    // The Submit Button ActionPerformed event  
    private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        // Gather the supplied Data...
        String name = nameTextField.getText();   
        String occupation = occupationTextField.getText();
        String ageCategory = ageCategoryList.getSelectedValue().toString();
        String employment = employmentCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        boolean filipino = filipinoCheckBox.isSelected();
        String tin = tinTextField.getText();
        String gender = genderRadioButton1.isSelected() ? "Male" : 
                        genderRadioButton2.isSelected() ? "Female" : "Unknown";
        
        // Display this gathered Data in the other form...
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SubmissionForm(name, occupation, ageCategory, employment, filipino,
                                tin, gender).setVisible(true); 
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Now the **SubmissionForm** class. Notice the constructor and the code within it. Also notice that there is no **main()** method in this class:

```
public class SubmissionForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    // Class Constructor...
    public SubmissionForm(String name, String occupation, String ageCategory, 
                          String employment, boolean isFilipino, String tin, 
                          String gender) {
        initializeForm();
     
        // JLabel components on this form
        lblName.setText(name);
        lblOccupation.setText(occupation);
        lblAgeCategory.setText(ageCategory);
        lblEmployment.setText(employment);
        lblPhilipino.setText(String.valueOf(isFilipino).toUpperCase());
        lblTIN.setText(tin);
        lblGender.setText(gender);
    }

    private void initializeForm() {
        // Your code to initialize form components here...
    }

}
```

You could place all the gathered data into an Array, ArrayList, or List Interface and pass that through the constructor and then work with that collection of data before the form is displayed.

The code above is not a runnable. It was supplied off the top of my head and therefore may contain some small errors.

In other words ... create a constructor similar to what was done here for your second form.

Comment: How about the image selected? I used the jDesktopPane to select the image file to show to jLabel2 as written in my code